# Bundler could not find compatible versions for jquery-ui-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gemset

I've created a new gemset, then, when I try to bundle install, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-ui-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0) ruby

    alchemy_cms (~> 3.0.0.rc5) ruby depends on
      jquery-ui-rails (4.1.1)
```

Although, I've `apt-get update`, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the version constrain from `alchemy_cms` in `Gemfile` and run:

```
bundle update
```